# How to re-mock a json file import in each vitest test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vite, vitest

I have a function named `validateData()` that imports a json file (data.json), and validates that the data is not missing any field.
I want to write multiple `vitest` test to test that function, and I want each test to mock the json file differently.

I tried mocking with `vi.mock` and making sure the default import is hoisted, like this:

```
const mocks = vi.hoisted(() => {
  return {
    default: vi.fn(),
  };
});

vi.mock('data/data.json', () => {
  return {
    default: mocks.default,
  };
});

const obj1 = {
  id: 1,
  name: "obj1"
}

describe('validateData', () => {
  test('with valid data', () => {
    mocks.default.mockReturnValueOnce({ obj1 });
    expect(validateData()).toStrictEqual([]);
  });
  test('with missing field', () => {
    mocks.default.mockReturnValue({ obj1: { ...obj1, name: undefined } });
    expect(validateData()).toStrictEqual(['Missing name for obj1']);
  });
});
```

while the data json file look like this:

```
{
 obj1: {
   id: 1,
   name: "obj1"
 }
}
```

This still doesn't work, the `validateData` function is still using the actual json and not the mock.